# deploying django application to google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, django-deployment

I have followed through the steps in google cloud platform guide, but still getting permission error. which says the caller does not have the permission. pls what am I doing wrong.
this is the out of command `gcloud config list`

```
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-f
[core]
account = <gmail-account>
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = <project-id>
Your active configuration is: [default]
```

**this is the error it raised**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/<project-id>/regions/europe-west1/operations/error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-07-28T15:45:31.962Z49210.jv.11: Deployment Manager operation <project-id>/operation-... errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-..../resources/aef-default-...."
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",
\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",
\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,
\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",
\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",
\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",
\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/<project-id>/regions/europe-west1/autoscalers\",
\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
```

Comment: Which guide did you follow and what commands are you running to produce the error?

Comment: i ran 'gcloud app deploy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your [project quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) usually this error is raised when your project doesn't have enough IPs or VMs (App engine Flex uses Compute Engine VMs) and the scaling strategy on your `app.yaml` is exceeding the quotas.

Please try to add one of the following blocks in your `app.yaml` file

For automatic scaling

```
automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
```

For manual scaling

```
manual_scaling:
   instances: 2
```

To avoid exhaust these quotas please, delete/stop the App Engine service versions that you don't need.

For more information about scaling strategies please check this [reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#services)

For example:
Every VM takes 1 IP and your project have a quota of 4.

If your app engine service has 3 VMs running (3 IPs used), in the next deploy you only has 1 IP available, if your `min_instances`  or `instances` in your `app.yaml` file is greater than 1, the deploy will fails.

This is because is not possible allocate more than 4 IPs on your project, and App engine first turn on the new instances and after shutdown the old instances, this is to avoid a service interruption

If you need increase this resource quotas it is necessary to [contact a GCP sales rep](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

Comment: if I check my project  qouta, how do i know that ips and vms is not enough?

Comment: @EmekaVictorLivingstone for example every vm takes 1 ip and your project have a quota of 4.

if your app engine service has 3 VMs running (3 ips used), in the next deploy you only has 1ip available, if your `min_instances` or `instances` in your app.yaml file is greater than 1 the deploy will fails.

This is because is not possible allocate more than  4 IPs on your project, and App engine first turn on the new instances and after shutdown the old instances, this is to avoid a service interruption.

Comment: @EmekaVictorLivingstone if this answer was useful for you please do not forget to up vote an accept the answer

Comment: @ thanks. it was successful deployed. but I got another error, when I ran gcloud app browse. server error(500)

Comment: @lvingstone i think that you need open a new question for the new issue in order to have better visibility for people that are finding information about same issue

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177625/bad-request400-django-postgresql-page-error-in-gcp